# Alignment issue while implementing TableRow

Tags: android

I need to accomodate three columns in a TableLayout.

The following code creates the table row headers & then populates the values in the columns. Table layout has been defined in the layout xml.

```
TableLayout tableLay = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

// Table Headers
TextView firstNameHeader = new TextView(this);
firstNameHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
TextView lastNameHeader = new TextView(this);
lastNameHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
TextView ageHeader = new TextView(this);
ageHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


// Adding the Table headers to Table Row  
TableRow empHeaderTableRow = new TableRow(this);
empDetailsTableRow.addView(firstNameHeader);
empDetailsTableRow.addView(lastNameHeader);
empDetailsTableRow.addView(ageHeader);

// Adding the Table Row to Table Layout
tableLay.addView(empDetailsTableRow);

// Adding Column Data

for(int count = 0; count < empDetails.size ; count++){
TextView firstNameData = new TextView(this);
firstNameData.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
firstNameData.setText(...);
TextView lastNameData = new TextView(this);
lastNameData.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
lastNameData.setText(...);
TextView ageData = new TextView(this);
ageData.setText(...);
ageData.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

TableRow empDataTableRow = new TableRow(this);
empDataTableRow.addView(firstNameData);
empDataTableRow.addView(lastNameData);
empDataTableRow.addView(ageData);
}

// Adding the Table Row to Table Layout
tableLay.addView(empDataTableRow);
```

There is alignment issue with the above code.
When any of the data like first name , last name exceeds a certain length , the entire colum shifts out of the screen. In that case , only one column is visible on the screen while the rest of the columns goes beyond the screen.

I want to set fixed column width for the three columns  , so that if any data wrt to a particular column exceeds length, it will get truncated or displayed on the second line & the other column positions (aligned) is not disturbed.

Do I need to truncate the text if it exceeds the column width or it can be done automatically with the help of any method already available in TextView.

Any hints/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width of textView to be fixed to resolve this issue. You can also use weight for this purpose.

Comment: LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 20, (float) 1.0);   I  set the layout to every TextView by adding textView.setLayoutParams(layout) i.e. by providing same weight to all the columns but having a display issue.

Comment: LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (float) 1.0);

Answer (score 0):

Use [`android:shrinkColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android%3ashrinkColumns) and [`android:stretchColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android%3astretchColumns) xml-attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textview.setMaxLines(maxlines) and textview.setwidht() to fix this problem.